# Multiple IF statements with mathematical calculation

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I am trying to create a calculated column with IF statements..

E.g.

If colour(column A) =  green, red, blue, black then = (column B - column C)*6
If it is not any of those colours then it equals zero..

Every time I make my statements, it gives the formula in text as the result any help with the his will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Create a calculate column with the following formula:

```
=IF(OR([column A]="green",[column A]="red",[column A]="blue",[column A]="black"),([column B]-[column C])*6,0)
```

[image]

Testing result:

[image]